# Once OAuth dance is done with Flask-Dance-SQLA, best way to hit the actual API?

Tags: python, flask, flask-dance

I'm working off: https://github.com/singingwolfboy/flask-dance-google-sqla and got the OAuth template dance to work.

I've been trying to get some code to work with to hit the Google Calendar API, what's the best way to do this with the way that template is set up?

Is this directionally the right way to do it? Or is there a session object with attached headers I can use directly?

I've been trying things like getting the token (from the SQLAlchemy database) and doing a requests.post it, but getting back a Not Found.

```
def get_token():
    return OAuth.query.filter_by(user_id=current_user.id).first().token

@app.route("/get_events")
def get_events():
    token = str(get_token())
    req = requests.post('https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3', headers={'Authorization': token})
```

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier to use the `google` session object that Flask-Dance provides, like this:

```py
from flask_dance.contrib.google import google

@app.route("/get_events")
def get_events():
    if not google.authorized:
        return redirect(url_for("google.login"))
    req = google.post("/calendar/v3")
    # ... do whatever you want with this data
```

The `google` session object will automatically load the OAuth token from the storage -- in your case, SQLAlchemy. However it can only load it if the token has been stored at some point in the past, which is why it's a good idea to check `google.authorized` -- if it's False, then there is no token.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Perfect! Got it to work.

I do get oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.TokenExpiredError now, even though I just logged out and logged in again, and google.authorized is passing. I'm still using the basic flask-dance-google-sqla template here with nothing custom. Any thoughts? Thanks!!